# VIM - NerdTree command for opening all sub-folders under a folder in NerdTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

In VIM-NerdTree, I press Enter to open a folder but how do I open a folder and all its sub-folders in NerdTree through a single command?

I don't want to open any file. I just want all sub-folders to be open so that I can view the various filenames.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you press <kbd>?</kbd> you see the help. <kbd>O</kbd> opens recursively the nodes. <kbd>o</kbd> just opens the nodes. I think you need one of those.

Comment: I was replying "Just go on a dir and press "O" (uppercase o). It will recursively open all its subfolder. Very nice feature. BTW, if you press "?" when you are in NERDTree it will display a very nice help" :)

Comment: Thanks guys. Perfect! Didn't know about the ? command. Quite a useful command.

Comment: *X* (uppercase *x*) to **undo** (i.e close all child nodes)

Answer (score 5):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but doesn `O` do what you need? (capital o)